# Multiple left joins, how to output in php

Tags: php, mysql, double, outer-join

I have 3 tables I need to join.  The contracts table is the main table, the 'jobs' and 'companies' table are extra info that can be associated to the contracts table.

so, since I want all entries from my 'contracts' table, and the 'jobs' and 'companies' data only if it exists, I wrote the query like this....

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts
        LEFT JOIN jobs ON contracts.job_id = jobs.id
        LEFT JOIN companies ON contracts.company_id = companies.id
        ORDER BY contracts.end_date";
```

Now how would I output this in PHP?  I tried this but kept getting an undefined error "Notice: Undefined index: contracts.id"...

```
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql,$connection) or die ("Fail.");

if(mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result))
    {
       $contract_id = stripslashes($row['contracts.id']);
       $job_number = stripslashes($row['jobs.job_number']);
       $company_name = stripslashes($row['companies.name']);
    ?>
        <tr id="<?=$contract_id?>">
           <td><?=$job_number?></td>
           <td><?=$company_name?></td>
        </tr>
    <?  
    }
}else{
    echo "No records found";
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you may want to use "alias" to make the process of getting the data simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names will not be prefixed like this - and with each table having a column called "id" you could be in trouble. You should explicitly identify the columns you want returned rather than using "select *", and you then just retrieve the column by name un prefixed (e.g. `$row['job_number']`).

Answer (score 0):

The below would solve you problem.

```
$sql = "SELECT contracts.id AS contract_id, jobs.job_number, companies.name FROM contracts
        LEFT JOIN jobs ON contracts.job_id = jobs.id
        LEFT JOIN companies ON contracts.company_id = companies.id
        ORDER BY contracts.end_date";
```

Your problem is likely to be realted to the fact you are using two tables with the field `id` this is why you should select them as an alias using the mysql `as` clause.

You may also want to look into using a naming convention for your fields and sticking with it. For example, check out the theory of `Hungarian Notation`, this would stop issues like this from arrissing.

Comment: Doesn't entirely solve the problem, which is related to the retrieval of columns using prefixed names.